# excel copy past repeat macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, macros

At the moment I am working on a research project for my university in excel. Now I have a certain range BF1:DJ293 which has to be copied and past for 238 times to the right. So this range has to be copied to DK1: FO293 etc etc. So exactly next to the previous copy. I have no idea how to write macro's and I was wondering if any of you guys had an idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: How many total columns will that be?

Comment: Or if you mean the range size: 57 columns

Comment: As long as it isn't over the max of [16,384](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010342495.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So something like this will take the range A1:10 and copy it to C1:D10

```
Sub test()
Range("A1:B10").Copy
Range("C1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

What we need is a way to calculate how large the range will be and use that while we iterate. Something like this should work -

```
Sub test()
Dim start As Integer
Dim finish As Integer
Dim change As Integer

start = Range("BF1").Column
finish = Range("DJ293").Column
change = finish - start

For i = 1 To 238
    Range(Cells(1, start), Cells(293, finish)).Copy
    Cells(1, finish + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    start = (Cells(1, finish + 1).Column)
    finish = start + change
Next

End Sub
```